# How to renew the list with each iteration of loop in python

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop

I have a code chunk

```
if show_relations:
    _print('Relations:')

    entities = graph['entities']
    relgraph=[]
    relations_data = [
        [
            
            entities[rel['subject']]['head'].lower(),
            relgraph.append(entities[rel['subject']]['head'].lower()),
            
            rel['relation'].lower(),
            relgraph.append(rel['relation'].lower()),
            
            
            entities[rel['object']]['head'].lower(),
            relgraph.append(entities[rel['object']]['head'].lower()),
            _print(relgraph)
            
        ]
        for rel in graph['relations']
        
    ]
```

I created a `relgraph` list. Append the entries of list. With each iteration, I want to recreate this list.
Also, dump these lists into `json` file. How do I do that.

I tried to put `relgraph=[]` before and after `for` statement but it gives me an error saying `invalid syntax`

Comment: You're confusing a `for` loop with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written isn't a `for` loop, it's a list comprehension that has been sort of hacked up to behave like a `for` loop by putting a bunch of statements into tuples.  Don't do that; if you want to write a `for` loop, just write a `for` loop.  I think what you're trying to write is:

```
relations_data = []
for rel in graph['relations']:
    relgraph=[]
    relgraph.append(entities[rel['subject']]['head'].lower()),
    relgraph.append(rel['relation'].lower()),
    relgraph.append(entities[rel['object']]['head'].lower()),
    relations_data.append(relgraph)
```

If you were to write this as a list comprehension, you'd do it by building the individual `relgraph` lists in place via *another* comprehension, not by binding a name to it and doing a bunch of `append` statements.  Something like:

```
relations_data = [
    [i for rel in graph['relations'] for i in (
        entities[rel['subject']]['head'].lower(),
        rel['relation'].lower(),
        entities[rel['object']]['head'].lower(),
    )]
]
```